# Allow push notifications dialog in android

Tags: android, notification, modal-windows, dialog, alerts

We are creating an alert to the user asking for permissions on sending push notifications. We need this in ios and android.

The thing is that even though I found an example in ios (find attached) I downloaded several android same apps and this message didnt appear.

Is it because android doesnt need to ask this to the user when they initiate for the first time the app? And if android does ask this question...do you have an example of a real app or how this same message should be showed in a dialog for android lollipop?

Because what I know is that following android design guidelines dialog titles should be short so maybe android displays differently this information and content. How this same ios message should be in android?

Thanks for helping me with this. I have been searching and struggling for quite a time now.

Regards.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you download an application from google play it gives you a list of app permissions that are needed. When you continue with the download and installation of the app you essentially agree to let the app use these permissions.

Apps typically have a config section where users will be able to control things such as the amount/type of push notifications they would like to receive.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As per the Android guidelines, for every application installed the Play store or Web interface shows a dialog with all permissions that the application will use. By accepting this, you are providing the app permissions to use Push notifications in your application. There is no explicit confirmation made from user like as in iOS.

However if you wish the user be able to disable the push notifications, you may use a Switch in the Settings page of your application so that user can opt out of push notifications if they wish to.

**Update:**
From Android M and upwards this feature will be available within the OS. Google has announced unified app settings and run time app permissions on Android in the Google IO event held recently.